# How to attach browser and my web Application

Tags: asp.net

Dear All,
          I am working on the Web application, at time of run the my application open login page but browser disconnect from my application. So I am not able to debug the code.
Please help how to stop this disconnectivity between browser and my web application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio then all you need to do is put a breakpoint in a method that you know is going to be hit in order to debug the code i.e. your login forms page_load method.
A more fundamental point is that the client/web server model is stateless and that there will be no connection between your browser and the server between requests.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few answers here depending on what you are doing. If you are using the built in web server in Visual Studio you simply have to set break points within your code. If on the other hand you are using IIS and Visual Studio in combination then all you need to do is set a break oint in your code and attach Visual Studio to the relevant w3svc worker process, if in doubt select them all.

It's something I do virtually every day and it works very well indeed.

simes